# python - what to do when you get an oop object and need specific attribute info

Tags: python

As I program in tkinter, I will often print variables to the command line in Jupyter to see information that might not show up in the GUI.  This works well, but sometimes I get feedback, like this:

```
<someobject.workbook.Workbook object at 0x000001F749728148>
```

Or, if I run, a print(type(whatever_object)), I will get something like this:

```
<class 'someobject.workbook.Workbook'>
```

Those are helpful at times, but usually what I am looking for is the value of an attribute or info on the way a method might be functioning.

When this situation arises - is there a way to get inside the object to get more precise info on it?  The statements listed above are too general sometimes.

Comment: Try `>>> help(someobject)` or `>>> help(someobject.some_method)`

Comment: Add `?` to see help, `??` to see the source code: `someobject.method?`, 'someobject.method??`

Comment: `>>> dir(someobject)` can also be quite useful at times https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: Where should I add those?  Like right in the script? Or in a separate jupyter cell after the code has executed an generated the output on the command line?

Comment: @ArnieHopkins Just write it in a separate code cell

Comment: protip: if you want somebody besides OP to get notified, @mention them

Comment: @Marat: what do you mean?  I am not good at this social networking and ranking thing, but I will be happy to give credit as best I can.  Is this comment like what you mean?

Comment: oh, it is not about credit. If you have a follow-up question to one of the comments, the author is not notified by default and won't notice you asked. Unless you use a mention - then it'll get in their stackexchange inbox and they'll have a chance to follow up

Comment: also `dir(somobj)` to see the methods/attributes